# Mikrotik CloudCore1036 static DHCP configuration using multiple NIC - LAN and WLAN

Tags: wireless, ipv4, dhcp, mac-address

**My question is it possible to configure CC1036 like a DHCP server which would be able to:**

1. gives to specified host (for example Local Station 5) same **IPv4** address based on his **MAC LAN** and **MAC WLAN** address - it means that no matter of how host connect using his **WLAN NIC**  or **LAN NIC** (through switch or AP) it receive **same** IPv4 address ?

---

[image: Mikrotik CloudCore1036 static DHCP configuration using multiple NIC - LAN and WLAN]

At above picture You can see part of my network scheme. Main router based on Mikrotik **CloudCore1036** within one bridge and **HP** switches **1810-24G** and **1810-8G** - all default configured within default VLAN. All **CC1036** interfaces were **arp-proxy** and **arp-enabled** mode.

- **CloudCore 1036** - main router with one bridge and included one link bond using **802.3ad** protocol,
- **rtr-a-x** - **MikroTik 2011 UiAS-2HnD-IN (WiFi)** router configured as **ap-bridge** without any **DHCP** server,
- **swt-d-x** switches - my distribution layer switches; all **HP 1810-24G - J9803A** with one default VLAN,
- **swt-a-x** switches - my acces layer switches; all **HP 1810-8G - J9802A** with one default VLAN,
- **Server NAS**- my local storage server,
- **Local station x** - hosts connected to the network using **DHCP server** defined at **CC1036** MikrotikRouter,
- **Bonding-1** - I bounded 3 links between **CC1036** and **swt-d-1** switch; at **swt-d-1** I used **trunks** at **E22**,**E23**,**E24** interfaces and at **CC1036** at **E1**,**E2**,**E3** I used **balanced-rr** protocol and I add that Bond to the bridge,
- **Bonding-2** - I bounded 2 links between **CC1036** and **swt-d-3** switch; at **swt-d-3** I used **trunks** at **E23**,**E24** interfaces and at **CC1036** at **E7**,**E6** I used **802.3ad** protocol and I add that Bond to the bridge.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if client provides the same clientid and you have static configuration for the client on the dhcp server already. Do not forget to delete mac address for the static configuration and leave the clientid part. Also lower the lease time as dhcp server will not check the ip if is it statically configured.

See

http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/DHCP_Server

Comment: And where is the place where I can define hosts ClientID at CC1036 ?

Comment: IP->DHCP Server->Leases

There are all entries with DHCP leases. Non-static ones have D in the first column. If you click on them you can erase mac address and leave/specify clientid and it should work like you want - to have same address irrespective of link type. But for this to work you need to have bridged network (=same physical nework) for both cable connections and wifi connections.

Comment: Now i have one IPv4 nettwork - 192.168.1.0/24. So what You are going to tell is that if I set couple networks this kind DHCP wouldn't work ?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You will need to [override the mac address on the endpoints wifi adapter](http://visihow.com/Change_the_MAC_address_of_your_Wireless_Adapter) using the same mac address as the wired nic.  Then, configure static DHCP as [shown here](http://www.mikrotik.com/testdocs/ros/2.8/ip/dhcp.php).

Comment: What do You mean that I need ovverride MAC address ? Which port, devices and why ? Why I need do anyhthing with MAC addreses ? You mean I should clone MAC's to be identical at WiFi and LAN interface ? Thats Your point ?

Comment: Exactly because looking at the documentation I do not see where you can assign the same IP to 2 different mac addresses.  So, my thought is that you might be able to use the same mac address for wired and wireless - assuming that only one will be in use.

Comment: Hmmm it is an option :) I will try it soon.